# C# HasMorePages giving me trouble understanding it

Tags: c#

What's wrong with this code?

Once it reaches `HasMorePages` it keeps looping on that line

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e) {
    while (i<10)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Onga Bonga", new Font("tahoma", 12), Brushes.Black, 30, 30*i);

        if(i==5)
           break;

        i++;
    }

    e.HasMorePages = (i < 10);
}
```

Comment: cause you break at i==5? so i<10 is true to infinity...

Comment: so if i want to print 5 lines on one page and 5 on other how can i do it

Comment: sorry in advance as i am newbie

Comment: __Lesson Number One__: Better define __variables with nice names__ like `linesPerPage = 5` or `totalLinesPrinted = 0` or `currentLineOnPage++`  Once you have that, the code writes itself and will always stay readable..!

Comment: ok i will keep that in mind from now on thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to the second page, the condition `i==5` will be true again, and the loop will end after writing out one line, but without increasing the variable `i`. It will continue to write that line on page after page.

Get the index that you start with, and calculate the last index for the current page. Also, make the check after increasing the variable, otherwise you will repeat the last item of the first page as the first item on the second page:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e){
  int last = i + 5;
  while (i<10) {
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Onga Bonga", new Font("tahoma", 12), Brushes.Black, 30, 30*i);
    i++;
    if (i > last) break;
  }
  e.HasMorePages = (i < 10);
}
```

Comment: that's not fair. 2nd time today that i lost an accepted answer (why?). but anyways... good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int m_myPageIndex = 0;

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    switch(m_myPageIndex)
    {
        case 0: // print first page
          for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
          {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Onga Bonga", new Font("tahoma", 12), Brushes.Black, 30, 30*i);
          }
          m_myPageIndex++; 
          e.HasMorePages = true;
          break;
        case 1: // print next page
          for(int i=5;i<10;i++)
          {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Onga Bonga", new Font("tahoma", 12), Brushes.Black, 30, 30*i);
          }
          e.HasMorePages = false;
          break;
    }
}
```

Have a look at how a for/while/switch/if/else works.